# Vuetify: How to specify the background-color of a selected item in v-select component

Tags: background-color, vuetify.js, selected, v-select

I have a v-select widget (combobox / select) in a Vue application. When I open it and hover over an option, the background-color of the option is highlighted (currently light-grey). I want the background-color to have a different color when the mouse arrow hovers over an option. I can not see a property of the v-select widget that supports this. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
v-select::hover {
  background-color: "#00857A";
}
```

```
<v-select
    append-icon="../assets/img/sy-arrow-chevron-down.svg"
    background-color="white"
    :height="68"
    item-text="label"
    item-value="key"
    class="mr-3"
    v-model="type"
    :width="421"
    :items="searchCriteria"
    @change="performSearch()"
  ></v-select>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `item-color` attribute to `v-select`

Answer (score 3):

Define color:

`.v-list-item--link::before { background-color: red; }`

Define opacity:

`.theme--light.v-list-item:hover::before { opacity: 0.64; }`

Comment: adding these styles makes no difference.

Comment: This pretty much worked for me, but the before element is transparent and floated over .v-list-item__title. I wanted a full opacity color which hid the text. I had to add z-index: 1; to see the text when hovered.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the official way to modify Vuetify: https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme

Comment: that's the proper solution. makes sense to keep all colors in the same color through the whole app.

Answer (score 0):

Add a style for listitem on hover:

```
div.v-select-list div[role=list] div[role=listitem]:hover {
    background-color:#00857A;
  }
```

and the background of the selected option will be colored darkgreen

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you, it worked for me

```
.theme--light.v-text-field--solo > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot {
    background:#9d2449 !important;
    color: white !important;
   
}

.theme--light.v-label {
    color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
}

.theme--light.v-select .v-select__selection--comma {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to give explanations and not only code for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

::v-deep to access the css.

```
::v-deep .v-list-item--link::before { background-color: red;  }

::v-deep .theme--light.v-list-item:hover::before { opacity: 0.64; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `bg-color` prop to your `v-select`.

```
<v-select 
 name="foo"
 label="foo"
 :items="['foo', 'bar']"
 bg-color="red"
/>
```