# Change icon color for v-select component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I set an icon to [`v-select`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects) component but I want to change its color to red.

[image]

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col class="d-flex" cols="12" sm="6">
          <v-select
            :items="items"
            label="Standard"
            prepend-icon="edit"
          ></v-select>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/begueradj-the-sasster/pen/povdWyj?&editable=true&editors=101)

How to colorize the icon ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? *[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361274/vuetify-how-to-specify-the-background-color-of-a-selected-item-in-v-select-comp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361274/vuetify-how-to-specify-the-background-color-of-a-selected-item-in-v-select-comp)*

Comment: It is not a clean solution there, thank you for the feedback. Actually I know the solution of this, I used it in the past, I just remembered it and it is listed in an answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the slot prepend

```
<v-select
  :items="items"
  label="Standard">
  <template v-slot:prepend>
    <v-icon color="red">edit</v-icon>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a clean approach ... I used it some weeks ago, but I forgot it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Check Vuetify documentation.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#selects

If you inspect the example, the html is:

```
<i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate material-icons theme--light">map</i>
```

Vuetify has abstract classes for colors. In this case: `.theme--light.v-icon`
The documentation of colors is:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors#

There you could select the color you want and via sass change it.
Furthermore, you could set it like:

```
.v-icon {
  color: ##0F0F0F;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change color simply using Markup

```html
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-container fluid>
          <v-row align="center">
            <v-col class="d-flex" cols="12" sm="6">
              <v-select
                :items="items"
                label="Standard"
                prepend-icon="edit"
              >
                 <template v-slot:prepend>
                  <v-icon color="green">edit</v-icon>
                </template>
              </v-select>

            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-app>
    </div>
```

See link: https://codepen.io/pen/BaymmWQ